# convert collListItem to data table

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

How to I convert a `collListItem` to a `dataset` or `datatable`.

I have tried below with no success.

```
SPListItemCollection collListItems = emp_info.GetItems(query);

dt = collListItems.GetDataTable();
```

Please see my code

```
 var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();

    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Megal');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    var ViewXml = "<View><Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Main_x0020_Heading' /><FieldRef Name='Sub_x0020_Heading' /><FieldRef Name='Sub_x0020_Heading_x0020_Order' />" +
       "<FieldRef Name='Links' /><FieldRef Name='Link_x0020_URL' /><FieldRef Name='link_x0020_order' /></ViewFields><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Main_x0020_Heading' />" +
       "<Value Type='Text'>HUMAN RESOURCES</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";

    camlQuery.set_viewXml(ViewXml);
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    //var dataTable = collListItem.GetDataTable();
    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SPClient.ListItemCollection listItems = spList.GetItems(camlQuery);
  clientContext.Load(listItems);
  clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
  DataTable dtGetReqForm = new DataTable();
  if (listItems != null && listItems.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var field in listItems[0].FieldValues.Keys)
                        {
                            dtGetReqForm.Columns.Add(field);
                        }

                        foreach (var item in listItems)
                        {
                            DataRow dr = dtGetReqForm.NewRow();

                            foreach (var obj in item.FieldValues)
                            {
                                if (obj.Value != null)
                                {
                                    string key = obj.Key;
                                    string type = obj.Value.GetType().FullName;

                                    if (type == "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue")
                                    {
                                        dr[obj.Key] = ((FieldLookupValue)obj.Value).LookupValue;
                                    }
                                    else if (type == "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue")
                                    {
                                        dr[obj.Key] = ((FieldUserValue)obj.Value).LookupValue;
                                    }
                                    else if (type == "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue[]")
                                    {
                                        FieldUserValue[] multValue = (FieldUserValue[])obj.Value;
                                        foreach (FieldUserValue fieldUserValue in multValue)
                                        {
                                            dr[obj.Key] += (fieldUserValue).LookupValue;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else if (type == "System.DateTime")
                                    {
                                        if (obj.Value.ToString().Length > 0)
                                        {
                                            var date = obj.Value.ToString().Split(' ');
                                            if (date[0].Length > 0)
                                            {
                                                dr[obj.Key] = date[0];
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        dr[obj.Key] = obj.Value;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    dr[obj.Key] = null;
                                }
                            }
                            dtGetReqForm.Rows.Add(dr);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: OP is looking for a javascript/client-side answer :)

Comment: yes javascript/client-side is what i need.